# Arch and KDE unable to login to paid WiFi network

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, kde

I am in a camping and would like to connect to the internet. The camping's WiFi is not protected by an SSID but by a custom page restricting the access to the internet. My trouble is in loading that page. When clicking on the login button from the KDE notification, it gets me to networkcheck.kde.org which fails to load. If I click on the Firefox notification, it redirects me to the correct URL of the camping's login page, but it doesn't load.
The WiFi works on android and windows devices, I have also achieved connecting it on my laptop but doesn't know why it doesn't work anymore.
I have tried playing with Firefox's and kde's network settings without success, I have tried disabling ufw but it didn't do anything. I have tried rebooting, disconnecting and reconnecting.
I have installed arch using archinstall and I think I copied the network config from the iso.

Comment: I think you're mixing up terms: "Not protected by an SSID": The SSID is the network ID that the access point broadcasts. It's what you'd call "network name". It's not a protection mechanism, just a network name.

Comment: maybe that AP is set up to selectively only redirect android & windows connectivity sites check. Try going to one of the usual android ones, e.g. http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com

Comment: Yes I meant IPV4 or 6. I tried using connectivity check.gstatic.com but it did the same as Firefox, it found the URL but couldn't load the page.

Comment: As an aside version gives you a free hour of wifi and you can use `macchanger` to change your mac address and just keep logging back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the experience that some paid Wi-Fi webpages don't work under Firefox on Linux and my solution was to install chromium to just log in to the Wi-Fi.